# How to develop a website for multiple timezones?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, timezone, cakephp-2.0

I am developing my e-commerce website by using cakephp2 and AngularJS.

I wanted to run my website in multiple countries and multiple timezones. I had set my timezone to:

```
date_default_timezone_set('asia/kolkata')
```

Now I set it to:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC')
```

Now I am converting all time to UTC format before storing to database. For example if a order is placed at `2017-Sep-12 3:30 AM` from India then its converted to UTC by subtracting `-5.30` hour from it. Now its will be `2017-Sep-11 22:00 PM`.

Now while email to customer its showing your order is placed at `Sep 11, 2017` instead of `Sep 12, 2017`

Comment: You need to store each user's timezone.

Comment: The probable easiest approach is to use "1 hour ago" instead. Then just specify that all times are in a given timezone, like you `2017-09-11 20:05:59 GMT` for instance

Comment: You need to convert it back to the original timezone when showing to an user. In this case, convert the UTC date/time back to India timezone.

Comment: User can can place order from any timezone. He may register himself initially from some other timezone. Is there any solution without storing user timezone?

Comment: If dates can come from any timezone, it's better to store them as UTC. But when showing to an user, you need to know which timezone you'll convert to, otherwise all users will see the date in UTC.

Comment: Can we do that without storing user timezone @Hugo?

Comment: Just think about how you would convert to the user's timezone without knowing it. You'll have to get it somewhere. As your code runs in the server, the only way is to store it. You could also use the browser's default timezone and display the date using javascript, but it's not a reliable config, as it can change and you can't control it. I think the best is to store it.